# Distinct on multiple columns in datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Trying to do what a SQL query (`SELECT DISTINCT (first,second),third FROM table`) would do but I am doing it with LINQ and a datatable.

---

**EDIT**

SQL should look like a Mysql

`select first, second, third
 FROM table
 group by first, second`

---

```
DataTable secondTable = new DataTable();
secondTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
secondTable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
secondTable.Columns.Add("clockIn", typeof(string));
secondTable.Columns.Add("clockOut", typeof(string));

var t4 = (from a in firstTable.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    name = a.Field<string>("name"),
    date = a.Field<string>("date"),
    clockIn = a.Field<string>("clockIn"),
    clockOut = a.Field<string>("clockOut")
}).Distinct();

var t5 = (from a in firstTable.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    name = a.Field<string>("name"),
    date = a.Field<string>("date")
}).Distinct();

var t6 = (from d in t5
          join a in t4
          on new
          {
              d.name,
              d.date
          }
          equals new
          {
              a.name,
              a.date
          }
          select secondTable.LoadDataRow(
          new object[]
          {
               d.name,d.date,a.clockIn,a.clockOut
          }, false)).ToList();

ViewBag.Data = secondTable;
```

What this code is doing is, it is joining `t4` and `t5` in `t6` with no exclusions. While what I desire is all rows from `t4` that are present in `t5` should join with `t6` on the basis on (name, date) AND all rows from `t5`that don't exist in `t4` should be excluded. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Where did `firstTable` come from?

Comment: @KaeL Imagine `firstTable` is the original table.

Comment: @KaeL while debugging, I have double checked, `t4` and `t5` have the desired records in them. I am only doing something wrong with the `t6`.

Comment: Sample input and output would clarify what you're trying to achieve. I don't quite understand your description.

Comment: @GertArnold, I have a table with 4 columns (`firstTable`) and I want to  apply `Distinct` based on its first two columns (i.e., if these two columns are duplicate, select only the first one) . What I have ended up doing is, I took those two columns out and applied `distinct` operator on them to get the unique rows in `t5`. Then I joined them to the original table's mirror table `(t4)`.

Comment: @GertArnold I've the desired rows in `t4` and `t5`. What I want to do from here is populate all rows from `t4` that are common in `t5` based on `date` and `time`.

Comment: Add samples + code instead of words. Words are fuzzy by nature.

Comment: Sql query `SELECT DISTINCT (first,second),third FROM table` should fail anyway, at least on most databases. MySql might allow that.

Comment: @GertArnold I've updated my question's ending part. Please review and let me know if you understand the issue or not. Thank You.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes it fails. I made up this query on my own to only show what I want to achieve.

Comment: How could a  `name / date` pair exist in t5 and not in t4 ? That's where i'm stuck !

Comment: @RehanKhan Yes, but it fails for a reason - if you have multiple possible values in the third column for each row, what value would you choose?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Good question. Select the first entry and leave the rest.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Good question, there is an entry in `firstTable` that is duplicated on `name/date` pair in `firstTable` and is not duplicating on the remaining columns of `firstTable`. This is why I created a separate data table `(t5)` with `name/date` pair and applied `Distinct` operator so the duplicate entry gets removed and then I am trying to join it back with `firstTable` in such a way that only common entries between `t5` and `firstTable` should exist.

Comment: @RehanKhan Yes, but that's not possible that way. If you have "a/b/c", "a/b/d" in t4, you'll have "a/b" in t5. So how could you choose which "triplet" is corresponding in t4 ? Anyway, one of your previous comments make things clearer.

Comment: Sorry for being such a nag, but first based on what order?

Comment: @ZoharPeled seems to be "as random as mysql group by" (when you don't group by all fields in mysql)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yeah, I never liked that behavior...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Good question. It should select "a/b/c" in t4, if it has "a/b" in t5 and if "a/b/c" is the first entry in t4. There has to be a way to tell it to select the first entry and drop the rest.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry .. order?

Comment: Yeah, you said "first". first implies order.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments, you may just group by the desired fields, and take any of the grouped result.

You may order by clockin or clockout to get a less "random" result.

```
var t6 = firstTable.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(a => new {
                                     name = a.Field<string>("name"),
                                     date = a.Field<string>("date")
                                     }
                            )
                   .Select(g => g.First())
                   //or Select(g => g.OrderBy(a => a.Field<string>("clockIn")).First()
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a red error line on `a.Field<string>("name")` and `a.Field<string>("name")` saying: 

Invalid annonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type member must be declared with a memeber assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: @RehanKhan edited, I don't work enough with datatables ;)

Comment: Althaus. Got it. Please delete your comment since you have corrected your answer. Thanks